# Proof that the area of a parallelogram is the product of any two adjacent sides and the sine of the angle between them.

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

[image]

given a parallelogram, show that the area of the parallelogram follows the relationship of two adjacent sides times sin of the angle between them.

I tried dividing the Parallelogram into two congruent triangles, then finding out if I could get a relationship using the law of sines since I am stuck on how to integrate sin of the diagonal into the relationship.

Comment: You have asked enough questions here to know that this is not a "do it for me" site. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help.

Comment: Great advice. But I mainly need someone to guide me. Can you look at the updated description to see if that can lend you some idea as to my problem?

Comment: @KevinPerez Break the parallelogram into two triangles, then lookup *area of a triangle* on wikipedia.

Comment: @dxiv there are many, should I use the 1/2absin() in this case?

Comment: You should not need more help after following the hint from @dxiv . Do some work on the problem yourself.

Comment: Alright, I will see what I can do. I have spent 1 hour already on this problem.

Comment: Oh I figured it out, I for some reason believed that you could not do the sin of the hypotenuse angle using that formula. but basically, it is just the sum of 1/2absinsin(B) two times for both triangles when you prove they are equivalent, so then there angles and sides are the same.